# Laravel Cashier Stripe set capture_method to manual

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later

In the stripe documentation above, they say that if you want to capture a payment hold to set the capture_method to manual and then when you're ready to finalize the charge, to send a capture request with the final amount.

I'm not seeing any documentation in the laravel cashier's implementation on how to do this.

however when I look in the code, I see that I can pass options that get merged in and I could set this I hope?

```php
trait Billable
{
    /**
     * Make a "one off" charge on the customer for the given amount.
     *
     * @param  int  $amount
     * @param  string  $paymentMethod
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return \Laravel\Cashier\Payment
     *
     * @throws \Laravel\Cashier\Exceptions\PaymentActionRequired
     * @throws \Laravel\Cashier\Exceptions\PaymentFailure
     */
    public function charge($amount, $paymentMethod, array $options = [])
    {
        $options = array_merge([
            'confirmation_method' => 'automatic',
            'confirm' => true,
            'currency' => $this->preferredCurrency(),
        ], $options);

        $options['amount'] = $amount;
        $options['payment_method'] = $paymentMethod;

        if ($this->stripe_id) {
            $options['customer'] = $this->stripe_id;
        }

        $payment = new Payment(
            StripePaymentIntent::create($options, $this->stripeOptions())
        );

        $payment->validate();

        return $payment;
    }

...

    /**
     * Create a new SetupIntent instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return \Stripe\SetupIntent
     */
    public function createSetupIntent(array $options = [])
    {
        return StripeSetupIntent::create(
            $options, $this->stripeOptions()
        );
    }
```

but that seems to set the payment_method and not the capture_method... I feel like this would cause problems if both were set.

As I'm writing this, I think the answer is to use the createSetupIntent function with my desired parameters then save the response so I can reference the intent later and finalize the charge.

Has anyone done this? Rather has anyone reading this done it themselves? and if so, is this the right solution?

Comment: hi i am facing the same situation how you handle it.. i am using laravel cachier for subscripiton. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although Laravel Cashier is amazing to start you on a subscription based model for your application, I always found Stripe's SDK way more useful, intuitive, and easy to use. Their documentation is amazing, I would suggest using the SDK itself.

Given that, you can continue to use Cashier for everything else and for this particular scenario you can make use of the SDK. For your case you'll have to create a PaymentIntent and like you said, set the capture_method to manual.

Here is an example using Stripe SDK (If you are using Cashier, you already have the package):

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
);

$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'amount' => 2000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'capture_method' => 'manual'
]);
```